# How to group and uniqe each row with ORACLE?

Tags: oracle

Anyone please help me, how to uniqe each row

```
SELECT T3.ID_JS,T5.DIVISI_AREA,T4.NAME_METHODE_REPAIR, T1.URUTAN AS SORT, TO_DATE(T1.TIME_FINISHED_WORK,'DD/MM/YYYY') AS DATE_FINISHED
            FROM TB_WORK T1 
            JOIN TB_INSPECTION T2 ON T1.ID_INSPECTION=T2.ID_INSPECTION
            JOIN TB_JOBSHEET T3 ON T2.ID_JS = T3.ID_JS
            JOIN TB_METHODE_REPAIR T4 ON T1.ID_METHODE_REPAIR=T4.ID_METHODE_REPAIR
            JOIN TB_DIVISI T5 ON T1.ID_DIVISI=T5.ID_DIVISI
            where t3.id_js=142414
            GROUP BY T3.ID_JS,T5.DIVISI_AREA,T4.NAME_METHODE_REPAIR, T1.URUTAN,TO_DATE(T1.TIME_FINISHED_WORK,'DD/MM/YYYY')
            ORDER BY T3.ID_JS, TO_DATE(T1.TIME_FINISHED_WORK,'DD/MM/YYYY') desc
```

[Result] (http://prntscr.com/sfpuuq)

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: uniqe row based on last date_finished

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those rows *are* unique, so I'll guess: there are two rows with `sort = 3` and you'd want to have only one. If that's so, regarding the fact that date value is the only thing that  makes difference, a simple way is to use aggregate function (such as `min` or `max`). I used `max`, but you can change it if you want:

```
  SELECT t3.id_js,
         t5.divisi_area,
         t4.name_methode_repair,
         t1.urutan AS sort,
         MAX (TO_DATE (t1.time_finished_work, 'DD/MM/YYYY')) AS date_finished
    FROM tb_work t1
         JOIN tb_inspection t2 ON t1.id_inspection = t2.id_inspection
         JOIN tb_jobsheet t3 ON t2.id_js = t3.id_js
         JOIN tb_methode_repair t4
            ON t1.id_methode_repair = t4.id_methode_repair
         JOIN tb_divisi t5 ON t1.id_divisi = t5.id_divisi
   WHERE t3.id_js = 142414
GROUP BY t3.id_js,
         t5.divisi_area,
         t4.name_methode_repair,
         t1.urutan
ORDER BY t3.id_js, date_finished DESC
```

You'd remove date column from `GROUP BY`; besides, if you wanted to select *distinct* rows, why didn't you apply `select distinct` instead of using `group by`? Result is the same, but - `group by` is generally used with aggregates, not to return distinct result.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. i never used max/min aggregate before.